# OpenGL - Transforming a cube

Tags: c, opengl

I've been learning OpenGL, and I decided to code a function to draw a unit cube centered at 0,0,0 so I could then transform it as I wished. It is made of 6 faces.

However, I can only transform one of the faces on my cube :(

Here's the code:

```
void myUnitCube() {

  glPushMatrix();
  glNormal3f(0.0,0.0, 1.0);       
  glTranslated(0.0,0.0,-0.5);
  glRotated(180, 0.0,1.0,0.0);
  glRectf(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5);  

  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  glNormal3f(0.0,0.0, 1.0);       
  glTranslated(0.0,0.0,0.5);
  glRectf(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5);  

  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  glNormal3f(0.0,0.0, 1.0);       
  glTranslated(0.5,0.0,0.0);
  glRotated(90, 0.0,1.0,0.0);
  glRectf(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5);  

  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  glNormal3f(0.0,1.0, 0.0);       

  glTranslated(-0.5,0.0,0.0);

  glRotated(-90, 0.0,1.0,0.0);
  glRectf(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5);  

  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  glNormal3f(0.0,0.0, 0.0);       

  glTranslated(0.0,-0.5,0.0);

  glRotated(90, 1.0,0.0,0.0);
  glRectf(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5);  

  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  glNormal3f(0.0,0.0, 0.0);       
  glTranslated(0.0,0.5,0.0);
  glRotated(-90, 1.0,0.0,0.0);
  glRectf(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5);   

  glPopMatrix();
 }
```

If I call `myUnitCube()` after:

```
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslated(-4,0,-3);
  glPushMatrix();
  glScaled(8,0.1,6);
```

The result is that only the first face to be drawn gets scaled. How do I work around this?
I understand this situation arises because of the `pop`s but I need them...

Thanks!

Comment: Are your pushes and pops matched?  Based on the code you gave, they are not.  This may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Yep, they're matched.

Comment: OK, fixed, turns out they weren't. Thanks. You can post that as an answer and I'll accept you.

Comment: You really shouldn't use this combination of matrix operations and immediate mode calls. This probably the least efficient way to draw a cube in OpenGL. The canonical cube example is creating a vertex array with the 24 vertices of a cube (each face has 4 vertices, a vertex is the combination of both normal, position, texture coordinates and the other attributes, so as soon as one of two vertices' attribute differ it are distinct vertices → different normal thus different vertex).

Comment: @datenwolf, Yes; all those pushes, pops, and calls are *really* inefficient.  A table-based approach is less fragile (not prone to as many copy-paste errors) and more efficient.

Comment: If you have unmatched push/pops and didn't detect them, you aren't calling glGetError. Do that _at least_ once per frame, and probably more when debugging.

Comment: @Macke: Actually you have to call glGetError in a loop: There are a number of error fields which accumulate. One shouldn't use glGetError to death, and also a GL error is no reason for throwing an exception. They should be used as diagnostic.

Comment: @datenwolf: The OP doesn't seem to know about glGetError at all, so I tried to point him in the right direction. There are of course more details about it, but no need to get picky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your matrix pushes and pops matched?  Based on the code you gave, they are not.  This may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yup, because every frame leaves more entries on the matrix stack, and eventually you run out, and push no longer works (then the first pop undoes the scaling, which explains the observed behavior).

Comment: @Ben Voigt, Thanks for explaining the reasoning behind the answer.